# When variable to define a PHP function in foreach, returns last item

Tags: php, function, variables

```
foreach ( $keys as $key ){
    $key['function_name'] = function (){
        global $key;
        $return = '<h3>'. $key['title'] .'</h3>';
        return $return;
     };
    // do someting with return.
}
```

when I do someting with return it always return me last title of $keys. What I need to do for getting specific title which I want with "$key['function_name']"

Comment: Only functions have return value.

Comment: Have you tried passing it through as a reference?

Comment: What do you mean? I am new with variable functions. There are title for every single $key var. @Roy

Comment: How can I do it? @Daerik

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? From what I understand, you want to use values in a loop to perform some computation.  One way to make this better is to write your method separately and call it during each iteration of the loop.

Comment: That's how loops work, from beginning to end. If you are looking for something in between you need to do an if statement and a break statement.

Comment: @Pila I can't write that method seprately. Beacuse I am using with database.

Comment: I've removed my answer because I realised it isn't useful if I don't understand your ultimate goal. In any case, using global variables is already hard enough by itself; making a loop variable global is even harder to get right. Perhaps you want to use the `use` syntax :-?

Comment: @RobertRocha I am not looking for special something. I need all of them with function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement:

```
$key['function_name'] = function (){
    global $key;
    $return = '<h3>'. $key['title'] .'</h3>';
    return $return;
 };
```

stores in `$key['function_name']` a function object. The code of the function is not executed at that point.

You run the function later, I guess after the `foreach`. When it runs, it expects to find the global variable `$key` that probably is the one you use to iterate over `$keys`. Since the iteration over `$keys` already completed, the value of `$key` is the last value assigned to it during the `foreach`.

The correct solution is to bind the current value of `$key` to the function  using the [`use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $key['function_name'] = function () use ($key) {
        return '<h3>'. $key['title'] .'</h3>';
     };
}
```

This way each function created during the `foreach` uses a different `$key`: the value of `$key` that was current when the function was created.